# Keep input value when click on mat-option Autocomplete - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making a real time Youtube search with Angular Material Autocomplete, but when I choose a mat-option, its value replace the input value. I want to keep the original value when click a mat-option and not be replaced.

I can set a new value through 'setValue' method of my FormControl, but I can't retrieve the original value of the input, it is immediately replaced when I click a mat-option

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 50%;">
   <input type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
   (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)" matInput 
   [formControl]="search" >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" 
  (optionSelected)="itemSelected($event)">
   <mat-option (click)="addToList(video)" *ngFor="let video of videos" 
     [value]="video.snippet.title">
     <img [src]="video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url" width="50">
     <span [innerHTML]="video.snippet.title"></span>
   </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: You can get access to the typed values by subscribing to `search.valueChanges` (the observable). Then you can maybe setup a logic to keep track of the previous values using the `rxjs` pairwise operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html).